# Trying to convert a 3 dimentional list into dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to python and I was trying to convert the following list into a dataframe.

To start I applied the following to an existing dataframe:

```
df1b=[df1a.iloc[:,:n].pct_change()]
df1b
print(type(df1b))
```

and the result I got is:

```
[                      A             B             C              D  \
 Date                                                                 
 2022-05-31           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
 2022-06-01     -0.004854     -0.006553     -0.002063      0.000000   
 2022-06-06      0.001330      0.003958      0.015162     -0.000339   
 2022-06-07      0.004872     -0.008541      0.008826     -0.003068   
 2022-06-08      0.001322      0.001325     -0.008748     -0.007289   
 ...                  ...           ...           ...           ...   
 2022-12-07     -0.005360      0.000656      0.002903      0.006578   
 2022-12-08     -0.003592     -0.003932      0.015195      0.004320   
 2022-12-09      0.001352      0.003289     -0.012117     -0.004411   
 2022-12-12     -0.003150     -0.005246      0.021645      0.002991   
 2022-12-13      0.003160      0.001978      0.000000      0.000000   
 
                        E              F            G  
 Date                                                  
 2022-05-31           NaN           NaN           NaN  
 2022-06-01      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000  
 2022-06-06      0.004129      0.010404      0.002574  
 2022-06-07      0.006773     -0.002818     -0.002243  
 2022-06-08     -0.008411     -0.010415      0.005496  
 ...                  ...           ...           ...  
 2022-12-07     -0.000378     -0.003718     -0.006345  
 2022-12-08      0.006671      0.002271      0.009224  
 2022-12-09     -0.012664     -0.002914     -0.006248  
 2022-12-12      0.017739      0.003564     -0.002653  
 2022-12-13      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000  
 
 [137 rows x 7 columns]]

<class 'list'>
```

when I applied the following to convert the list into a dataframe it says:

Prices = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']

df = pd.DataFrame(df1b, columns =['Prices'], dtype = float)

Error Message:

Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 137, 7)

Can anybody help?

Comment: This certainly does not look like a list  list does not print out `[137 rows x 7 columns]`. And if you try to create a dataframe providing a dataframe, alright, try this: `df = pd.DataFrame(df1b[0], columns =['Prices'], dtype = float)`

Comment: It's a list because of the extra outer brackets in the line, which makes it a list containing 1 dataframe: `df1b=[df1a.iloc[:,:n].pct_change()]`

Comment: It should just be `df1b=df1a.iloc[:,:n].pct_change()`

Comment: @DiMithras if I do print(type(df1b)) it gives me <class 'list'> so should be list

Comment: @corinthian74 anyway, have you tried the first comment?

Comment: @DiMithras yeah just did and it worked. Thanks all